# Check if a string is in an array of strings

Tags: powershell

I have an array of strings in `$info` from below command.

```
$info = Get-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\microsoft\windows\Currentversion\windowsupdate\" |
        select property |
        ft -hidetableheaders
```

When I try to get what is in `$info`, I got below output.

```
[cvs-tacoma01]: PS C:\Users\AdminJMandali\Documents> $info

{SusClientIdValidation, SusClientId}
```

Now I want to write an if condition by checking if `$info` contains either "SusClientIdValidation" or "SusClientId". I have tried below:

```
"$info" -match "SusClientId"
$info -contains 'SusClientId'
```

But the output for both is false. But `$info` clearly contains "SusClientId".

Comment: Are you sure `SusClientIdValidation`, `SusClientId` are strings ?

Comment: @scharette I don't know, by seeing them inside braces I thought they are strings.

Comment: Try removing the  | ft -hidetableheaders

Comment: `select property | ft -hidetableheaders` -> `select -Expand property`. **Do NOT** use `Format-Table` unless you're displaying data to a user.

Comment: Thanks guys. Appreciated. Expand worked.